# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Backup restore issue

Tags: 16.04, restore, duplicity

I created a backup using **`backups`** program before reinstalling my laptop; bigger hard drive.  I now cannot restore the backup, it ran through for a short while then looks to restore the same files again then fails with the below error.  Does anyone with experience know what the error below thinks the problem is?  There are some important data files in the backup I need to restore.

Thanks in advance!

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

```
 File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1532, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1526, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1380, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1457, in do_backup
    restore(col_stats)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 722, in restore
    restore_get_patched_rop_iter(col_stats)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 562, in Write_ROPaths
    ITR(ropath.index, ropath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/lazy.py", line 344, in __call__
    last_branch.fast_process, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/robust.py", line 38, in check_common_error
    return function(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 616, in fast_process
    ropath.copy(self.base_path.new_index(index))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 444, in copy
    other.writefileobj(self.open("rb"))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 620, in writefileobj
    buf = fin.read(_copy_blocksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 212, in read
    if not self.addtobuffer():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 237, in addtobuffer
    self.tarinfo_list[0] = self.tar_iter.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 344, in next
    self.set_tarfile()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 333, in set_tarfile
    self.current_fp = self.fileobj_iter.next()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 758, in get_fileobj_iter
    backup_set.volume_name_dict[vol_num],
KeyError: 68
```

Comment: When you say "re-install my laptop" what does that mean, then, did you backup to an external device ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I backed up to a USB hard drive.  I have tried restoring directly from it and copying the backup folder contents to the new Hard Drive to restore and they both fail as above.

Comment: It won't work by mere copying. These data files were in what folders before backup ?

Comment: If you mean the original location, its a backup of my home folder /home/cmyers.

Comment: Also, the backup program used duplicity so the files are in its compressed format with a form of index file.

Comment: If the original harddrive is still available, I would recommend either a) Clonezilla (http://clonezilla.org) or b) linux' `dd` utility (ref: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-can-i-use-dd-to-migrate-data-from-an-old-drive-to-a-new-drive)

Comment: The solution is this (from my experience) __create a new folder in /home/cmyers and restore there, then move the needed folders to where you need them__ the fact that you have re-installed new then it won't restore that well. Or like @Mark said using __clonezilla__ with the old system would be better.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it still fails with the above error when doing a full restore.  I only need a few of the folders back so happy to use the manual way.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

although I cannot find anything about the traceback code I can selectively restore from the archives via:

duplicity -t 3D --no-encryption --force --file-to-restore home/cmyers/VirtualMachines file:///Old-Ubuntu /home/c_myers/VirtualMachines/

At least I can get the files back that I want from the backup.

Cheers, Col.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have helped me (clearing the cache):

`mv ~/.cache/duplicity ~/.cache/duplicity.old`